# swift Redundant conformance of 'HomePageVCNEW' to protocol 'UITableViewDelegate'

Tags: swift

it is giving an error UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate

Redundant conformance of 'HomePageVCNEW' to protocol 'UITableViewDelegate'

```
import UIKit

class HomePageVCNEW: UITableViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {


    var arrayofCellData = [cellData]()

    @IBOutlet var tableview: UITableView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()


         arrayofCellData = [cellData(cell: 1,DisplayNameText: "TOM",StatusSubtitleText: "Tom's subtitle",ProfileImage:#imageLiteral(resourceName: "mark1"),AccountTypeImage:#imageLiteral(resourceName: "icon-72x72"),MoreOptionsImage: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "ADD BUTTON CENTRED")),cellData(cell: 2,DisplayNameText: "Ben",StatusSubtitleText: "Ben's subtitle",ProfileImage:#imageLiteral(resourceName: "tom3"),AccountTypeImage:#imageLiteral(resourceName: "B icon 72x72"),MoreOptionsImage: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "ADD BUTTON CENTRED")),cellData(cell: 1,DisplayNameText: "liam",StatusSubtitleText: "liam's subtitle",ProfileImage:#imageLiteral(resourceName: "denis2"),AccountTypeImage:#imageLiteral(resourceName: "icon-72x72"),MoreOptionsImage: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "ADD BUTTON CENTRED"))]

        // Uncomment the following line to preserve selection between presentations
        // self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = false

        // Uncomment the following line to display an Edit button in the navigation bar for this view controller.
        // self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem()
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }



    override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of sections
        return 0
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of rows
        return arrayofCellData.count
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {



        if
        arrayofCellData[indexPath.row].cell == 1{


            let cell = self.tableview.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)
                as! CustomCell



            cell.ProfileImage.image = arrayofCellData[indexPath.row].ProfileImage
            cell.MoreOptionsImage.image = arrayofCellData[indexPath.row].MoreOptionsImage
            cell.AccountTypeImage.image = arrayofCellData[indexPath.row].AccountTypeImage
            cell.DisplayNameLabel.text = arrayofCellData[indexPath.row].DisplayNameText
            cell.SubtitleStatusLabel.text = arrayofCellData[indexPath.row].StatusSubtitleText

            return cell


        }else if arrayofCellData[indexPath.row].cell == 2{

            let cell = self.tableview.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)
                as! CustomCell

            cell.ProfileImage.image = arrayofCellData[indexPath.row].ProfileImage
            cell.MoreOptionsImage.image = arrayofCellData[indexPath.row].MoreOptionsImage
            cell.AccountTypeImage.image = arrayofCellData[indexPath.row].AccountTypeImage
            cell.DisplayNameLabel.text = arrayofCellData[indexPath.row].DisplayNameText
            cell.SubtitleStatusLabel.text = arrayofCellData[indexPath.row].StatusSubtitleText

            return cell

        }else{



            let cell = self.tableview.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)
                as! CustomCell


            cell.ProfileImage.image = arrayofCellData[indexPath.row].ProfileImage
            cell.MoreOptionsImage.image = arrayofCellData[indexPath.row].MoreOptionsImage
            cell.AccountTypeImage.image = arrayofCellData[indexPath.row].AccountTypeImage
            cell.DisplayNameLabel.text = arrayofCellData[indexPath.row].DisplayNameText
            cell.SubtitleStatusLabel.text = arrayofCellData[indexPath.row].StatusSubtitleText
            return cell





    }


    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {




        if arrayofCellData[indexPath.row].cell == 1{
            return 49






       }else if arrayofCellData[indexPath.row].cell == 2{
            return 49





        }else{
     return 49








        }

    }

}


}//class
```

Answer (score 1):

Your class `HomePageVCNEW` extends `UITableViewController` which already conforms to `UITableViewDelegate` and `UITableViewDataSource`.

Replace:

```
class HomePageVCNEW: UITableViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

    // The rest of your code.
}
```

With:

```
class HomePageVCNEW: UITableViewController {

    // The rest of your code.
}
```

For more information check the last section of `UITableViewController`'s documentation: [UITableViewController relationships](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uitableviewcontroller#relationships).

Answer (score 1):

When a class inherits from UITableViewController, it by default conforms to `UITableViewDataSource` & `UITableViewDelegate` and you need not specify it. Try to remove both `UITableViewDataSource` & `UITableViewDelegate` after `UITableViewController`